# How to postion two centered DIVs overlapping each other and be responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to position two DIVs over each other so that when the pointer hovers over the picture the top one fades to show the one underneath. I did this here: http://quaystreet.chrisloughnane.net/

I want make it responsive so the pictures would scale to the horizontal width of the mobile device. Which is no problem with one picture but as soon as I try to re-position the underneath DIV it breaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisloughnane/f2NdQ/4/

Is it possible with just CSS to do what I want?

```
<div id='old'><img src="http://quaystreet.chrisloughnane.net/images/quay-street-old.jpg"/></div>
<div id='new'><img src="http://quaystreet.chrisloughnane.net/images/quay-street-new.jpg"/></div>

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go,

**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vinizinmoraes/f2NdQ/7/)**

CSS:

```
.images {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 354px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.images img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 354px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
      $('.images').on('mouseenter', function(){
          $('.images .old').fadeOut(1000);
      }).on('mouseleave', function(){
          $('.images .old').fadeIn(1000);
      });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <img class="new" src="http://quaystreet.chrisloughnane.net/images/quay-street-new.jpg">
    <img class="old" src="http://quaystreet.chrisloughnane.net/images/quay-street-old.jpg">    
</div>
```

Some things to you know:

1. To make each div in front of each other I am using position absolute.
2. I change the whole thing you did to make the div fadeOut, I think that way is more cleaner
3. I change your HTML to use the absolute position.
4. Your img will be width 100% and max-width `354px` can be any value just need to be the maximum width your img will use. So when is less then 354px he will use the whole div with 100%.

**Edit:**

If you don't care about [browser support](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) you can use CSS3 transitions, beware no IE<10.
 [Here is the answer with transition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792476/2274855)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript it's not really necessary. You can achieve the same behaviour with a smooth CSS3 transition

```
.images {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.images img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 354px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s linear 0s;
    transition: opacity .8s linear 0s;
}
.images img:first-child {
    z-index: 2;
}
.images img:first-child:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uNkY5/1/

Comment: Hey bro your link is equals to my

Comment: Aewsome dude, I love it! what about browser support?

Comment: All modern browser: on older browser it just degrades without transition